# Web socket url for vps?

Tags: javascript, java, websocket

I am trying to learn web socket. I developed one chatting web application it's working good on local server but not on my VPS. it seems that i am having some issue with my url "ws://" + document.location.host+"/TikTok/wschat". Please let me know if anyone could help me. I am learner and please don't mind my English. I am using linux based vps with java 8 and tomcat 7. Thanks in advance

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://tiktokchat.tk:8084/wschat' failed: Error
>   in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

```js
var ws=null;
var wsUri = "ws://" + document.location.host+"/TikTok/wschat";
console.log(wsUri);
ws = new WebSocket(wsUri);
ws.onmessage = function(message){
    document.getElementById("chatlog").textContent += message.data + "\n";
};
function postToServer(name){
    ws.send(name+">>>"+document.getElementById("groupMsg").value);
    document.getElementById("groupMsg").value = "";
};
function closeConnect(){
    ws.close();
};
```

```html
<div id='groupchat'>
<textarea id="chatlog" readonly></textarea><br/>
<input id="groupMsg" type="text" />
<button type="submit" id="sendButton" onClick="postToServer('${username}')">Send!</button>
<button type="submit" id="sendButton" onClick="closeConnect()">End</button>
</div>
```

```
package com.tiktok.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/wschat")
public class WsChat{
    //notice:not thread-safe
    private static ArrayList<Session> sessionList = new ArrayList<Session>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session){
        try{
            sessionList.add(session);
            //asynchronous communication
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Welcome!");
        }catch(IOException e){}
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session){
        System.out.println("close");
        sessionList.remove(session);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String msg){
        System.out.println("message");
        try{
            for(Session session : sessionList){
                //asynchronous communication
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg);
            }
        }catch(IOException e){}
    }
}
```

Comment: Is port `8084` open to the outside?

Comment: yes it is and sorry for  the late reply

Comment: and i also tried var wsUri = "ws://tiktokchat.tk:9295/wschat"; where 9295 is open

Comment: Does your VPS supports websocket? Your front-end server needs to support websocket first.

Comment: how do i know if it support or not? i read somewhere that vps support websocket.

Comment: And one more thing my tomcat and java support websocket

Comment: is 8084 or 9295 your secure port? In case of secure port, you'll need `wss://`

Comment: i am not using https. so no need of wss